# How to approach such integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

Sketch the region E bounded by the paraboloid $x = 1 - y^2 - z^2$ and the plane $x = 0$ $$\iiint_E y^2z^2 \,dV$$

I don't know what to do with $y^2z^2$ and how to convert it to polar or express it in some other way.

Comment: Is there anything missing in either of our answers?

Comment: no, you guys are great, thank you :) I just solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, integrate it with respect to $x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1-y^2-z^2$ to get
$$\iint[y^2z^2]x|_0^{1-y^2-z^2}dA=\iint y^2z^2(1-y^2-z^2)dA$$
From there, make the substitutions $r^2=y^2+z^2$,$y=r\sin\theta$, $z=r\cos\theta$, and $dA=rdrd\theta$. Your bounds are now $r=0$ to $r=1$ and $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$.

I think that this coordinate change would be cylindrical, as the $x$-axis remains the same and the $yz$-plane becomes the polar $r\theta$-plane.

Answer (score 0):

Do $y= r\cos\theta, z = r\sin\theta$, so $0\leq x\leq 1-r^2$, $0\leq r\leq 1$ and $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$.